# apple, multiple xib files connected to the same UIViewController class

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib

I just wanted to know if it's possible to have 1 UIViewController class connected to several xib files. basically I have some xib files that are very similar I don't want to make multiple controller for each one. I want to connect them all to a single UIviewcontroller class.

Thanks,

Comment: initWithNibName lets you specify the xib file to use for the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a) the method that you need. You just need to pass different .xib files when you instantiate the controller from code.